# Some keras and tensorflow functions crash R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I've searched but could not find a problem similar to mine. Basically, when I run basic functions from the keras or from the tensorflow packages such as the following list, they crash my R session:

```
> keras::dataset_imdb()
# R crashes

> keras::dataset_reuters()
# R crashes

> tensorflow::tf_config()
# R crashes

> tensorflow::tf_version()
# R crashes
```

Here's my sessionInfo() from the bareback R, where the issue also happens (ie, the problem is not specific to RStudio IDE):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2  Matrix_1.2-18   Rcpp_1.0.5      reticulate_1.16
[5] grid_4.0.2      jsonlite_1.7.0  lattice_0.20-41
```

I would gladly post here also some tensorflow information, but as you saw above they crash when I try getting them. For what it's worth, I ran tensorflow's [bug report template code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?labels=type%3Abug&template=00-bug-issue.md) in the anaconda prompt usind r-miniconda environment and I got the following output:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.version.GIT_VERSION, tf.version.VERSION)"
unknown 2.1.0
```

Before reporting a bug to tensorflow developers I wanted to check out if anyone here could share some pointer to the solution. It's probably something specific to the tensorflow and keras installation in my machine, not the code itself.
Thanks in advance; your time & help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything ran without a problem here. Also R 4.0.2, but on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thanks for testing and reporting back.